# How can I mark the position of -webkit-transform-origin?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I am using CSS3 to create CSS animations. I am rotating an image using rotateX. I would like to mark the position of the origin somehow so i can see exactly where the rotation point is.

How can I mark the position of -webkit-transform-origin? I am open to any solutions, CSS or JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

In the version of chrome I'm using (version 18), the `-webkit-transformation-origin` of any element is always initially the center of the element, **relative** to that element, where both coordinates are floored.  So if

`element.style.webkitTransformationOrigin`

is an empty string, then it would be

`Math.floor(element.width/2) + "px " + Math.floor(element.height/2) + " px"`.

If it isn't an empty string, then it will be in that format, `[x]px [y]px` with a space inbetween the two coordinates.  You can extract the values with a regular expression if need be, like in your case, and since the value is relative to the element, you're going to have to get the absolute position of the element on the page and add the origin to that to get the absolute position of your origin.

Comment: Does this solution actually place a physical marker at the point of origin so I can visually see the center point?

Comment: You made a typo in your answer, use : element.style.webkitTransformOrigin. 
Notice that for Chrome (05/14), the unprefixed version (transformOrigin) is there, but is undefined and has no effect.